# Starting docker service with "sudo docker -d"

Tags: shell, docker

I am trying to push some image to my registry, but when i tried to do:

```
    sudo docker push myreg:5000\image
```

i got some error that told me that i need to start docker daemon with

```
    docker -d --insecure-registry myreg:5000
```

So i stopped the docker service, and started it using the command above, once i do that the current shell window(ssh) is stuck with docker output, and if i close it the docker service is stopped.

I know this is an easy one, and i searched for hours and couldn't find anything.

Thank you

Comment: What linux distro are you running?

Comment: I'm missing the question... What are you trying to accomplish? What is the actual problem? Your push command should have a forward slash (`/`) instead of a backward slash.

Comment: The problem is that when i run the command, i get all the docker output to the shell, and if i close it, the docker service stopped, usually the -d should take care of it, but it wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that when i run the command, i get all the docker output to the shell, and if i close it, the docker service stopped, usually the -d should take care of it, but it wont work

I think there's a confusion here; the **top-level** `-d` (`docker -d`) flag starts docker in daemon mode, in the foreground. This is different from the `docker run -d <image>` flag, which means "start a container from `<image>`, in detached mode". What you're seeing on your screen, is the daemon output / logs, waiting for connections from a docker client.

Back to your original issue;

The instructions to run `docker -d --insecure-registry myreg:5000` could be clearer, but they illustrate that you should change the daemon options of your docker service to include the `--insecure-registry myreg:5000` option.

Depending on the process manager your system users (e.g., upstart or systemd), this means you'll have to edit the `/etc/default/docker` file (see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/articles/configuring/#configuring-docker)), or adding a "drop-in" file to override the default systemd service options; see [SystemD custom daemon options](https://docs.docker.com/articles/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options)

Some notes;

- The top-level `-d` option is deprecated in docker 1.8 in favor of the new `docker daemon` command
- Using `--insecure-registry` is discouraged for security reasons as it allows both unencrypted and untrustworthy communication with the registry. It's preferable to add your CA to the trusted list of your system.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer